# .htaccess redirect 301 not working with arguments

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, arguments

We recently rebuilt a client's website. They have found Google is listing some old links. We're trying to redirect these link just to the home page.

http://www.joiningtech.com/index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA
http://www.joiningtech.com/index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ

I have tried several ways to get these two redirects to work correctly by using the .htaccess file.

Method #1

```
redirect 301 http://www.joiningtech.com/index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA http://www.joiningtech.com/
redirect 301 http://www.joiningtech.com/index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ http://www.joiningtech.com/
```

Method #2

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ http://www.joiningtech.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ http://www.joiningtech.com/? [L,R=301]
```

I found these methods in other places in stackoverflow. I'm wondering if I've gotten something wrong and would appreciate any assistance!

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Stupid question, but have you made sure that rewrite is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks Kamil's help and some trial and error, I found the answer. This site is a WordPress site. The .htaccess file had the following in this order:

```
# suExec for PHP
Action application/x-pair-sphp /cgi-bin/php5.cgi
AddType application/x-pair-sphp .php
#Video MIME Types:
AddType video/m4v .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

</IfModule>
redirect 301 /pages/laser.html http://www.joiningtech.com/pages/welding.html
redirect 301 /index_nosound.html http://www.joiningtech.com/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ
RewriteRule .* http://www.joiningtech.com/? [L,R=301]
```

I'm guessing that the WordPress rewriting code and the later codes were conflicting. So I reordered the WordPress rewriting code to below the new redirects.

```
# suExec for PHP
Action application/x-pair-sphp /cgi-bin/php5.cgi
AddType application/x-pair-sphp .php
#Video MIME Types:
AddType video/m4v .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

</IfModule>
redirect 301 /pages/laser.html http://www.joiningtech.com/pages/welding.html
redirect 301 /index_nosound.html http://www.joiningtech.com/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ
RewriteRule .* http://www.joiningtech.com/? [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

This now works. I still need to know if it's ok to have two instances of "RewriteEngine On".

Comment: You need only one `RewriteEngine On`... the second is useless, but not an error

Answer (score 1):

Use lexicographical comparition, it's much clearer than regular expressions when you don't need them.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.joiningtech.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Your first method (using `Redirect`) doesn't work as you specify full `URL` as the first argument but it expects only the *pathname* part of the `URL`. Following will work as well:

```
redirect 301 /index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA http://www.joiningtech.com/
redirect 301 /index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ http://www.joiningtech.com/
```

The third way how to do it using `mod_rewrite` is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =GAW+CAM2&gclid=CMncjs-ehLQCFdKd4Aod52AAAQ
RewriteRule .* http://www.joiningtech.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. Unfortunately, neither of these solved the problem. I forgot to include your 2nd option in my original question because I had tried that as well. I used your first method using the lexicographical comparison. Unfortunately, the link is not stripping the argument so the link is still looking for GAW+...Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisB what do you mean with the "link is not stripping the argument"? You can also try third method (see updated answer) but I see no reason why shouldn't both first and second solution work...

Comment: Thanks so much @Kamil. This third method is still not functioning. It's very strange. What I mean by "link is not stripping the argument" is that when I try to go to the link: http://www.joiningtech.com/index.html?GAW+CAM2&gclid=CNbT06iehLQCFQWe4AodejAAkA instead of resolving to just www.joiningtech.com, it still shows the entire URL, thus not stripping all of the other characters after .com/.

Comment: @ChrisB make sure the `.htaccess` gets used. From what you say it seems the `.htaccess` is ignored. What do you get if you write some garbage in the `.htaccess` file? eg. "nonexistent" on the empty line...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's using the file. I took everything out of the .htaccess file and left only the word "nonexistent" in it and I got a 500 error. I replaced the file and the site came back up. Perhaps a problem is that it's trying to go to index.html?